# Azure Blob Shared Access Signature will work or not on generating new Storage Access Key

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have generated SAS using the primary access key. I want to know that if the primary & secondary access keys of the Storage Account are changed, will the SAS generated using the earlier Primary/Secondary access keys will continue to work or do I need to generate a new SAS every time the storage access keys are changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you regenerate the account keys, the SAS tokens created with the old key will become invalid (you will start getting 403 errors if you use them). You would need to generate new SAS tokens with new account keys.